# URI to XML parse

Tags: c#, .net, xml, recursion, xml-parsing

I need to convert the URI addres to XML notation. 
for example

```
/Test1/Test2/Test3/
```

to

```
<Modul>
<Test1/><Test2/><Test3/>
</Modul>
```

Here is my code:

```
private static XmlNode NodeRecurs(XmlNode node, string nodeName)
{
    string[] array = nodeName.Split('/');
    var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    var name = nodeName.Remove(0, array[0].Length + 1);
    XmlNode xmlNode = xdoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, array[0], string.Empty);
    node.AppendChild(xmlNode);

    if (array.Count() != 0)
    {
        NodeRecurs(node, name);
    }

    return node;
}
```

When the `NodeRecurs` calls itself it is `InvalidArgument` exeption. It says the it is wrong context for the current node.

Comment: You may not create a new XMLDocument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append nodes to a document, they need to be created by the *same* document.

You are creating a *new* `XmlDocument` every time you call the function - create one outside of the function and pass it in as a parameter.